# Сохранение даты в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Я обычно использую VARCHAR(255) и в `java` пишу `preparedStatement.setString(...)`. Но в SQL есть тип данных DATE и DATETIME.

Мне бы хотелось узнать как сохранять дату (без времени) в MySQL с типом данных DATE и читать ее?

Дополнительный вопрос: эффективнее хранить дату в DATE тип данных или VARCHAR(255)/TEXT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать в базе данных тип DATE, а в java коде - LocalDate. Во время запроса конвертируйте одно в другое. Пример:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select '2019-05-18'");
resultSet.next();
LocalDate date = resultSet.getDate(1).toLocalDate();
```

Что касается того, использовать дату или строку, то тут однозначно - дату. Имея дату, можно делать "range" запросы. Пример:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-01'
```

Comment: Еще есть тип `TIMESTAMP` если нужно учитывать временные зоны. Тут отличия: https://habr.com/ru/post/61391/